# Objective-C Safari Fails - Too Many Redirects - LinkSynergy - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, safari

So, I'm working on an iPhone application that I hope to make my money off of via redirects to iPhone games using Apple's link synergy program.  Problem is, the links are generating too many redirects and safari is saying "Safari can't open the page because too many redirects occurred".  My code is quite simple:

```
NSURL *toOpen=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=rSBwlRaBsug&offerid=146261.710610416&type=10&subid="];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:toOpen];
```

I'm using the application they send you too using the link synergy program, but the links just won't work on the iPhone.  Is there another link generator for the iphone or is there a way to link directly to iTunes but still get the 5% referral?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry. It is happened in Simulator only. On devices your code works perfectly. It is specific of iPhone Simulator.

So, you can use your code in development for any iPhone OS versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting cookies for the domain

Answer (score 0):

"It's the cydia addon categories!
Not if you have installe categories following problem can be caused:
- if you hide youtube app or put it into folder, it will automatically turn on content restriction and thus won't work in safari and as app
- if you have itunes or appstore in a folder or hidden this will cause all links which are supposed to be open with either of them, to be opened with safari giving you the error described above...."